Moveit & custom robot: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory Error
I just connected my custom robot with rviz & gazebo. Now I am planning trajectories using the rviz Moveit plugin. The robot always moves to the specified pose and then very often I get this error message:
[ INFO] [1712571483.570540244, 157.652000000]: Execution request received

[ERROR] [1712571493.481068124, 161.317000000]: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory (the expected upper bound for the trajectory 
execution was 3.645842 seconds). Stopping trajectory.

[ INFO] [1712571493.481265665, 161.317000000]: Cancelling execution for robot_arm/arm_controller

[ INFO] [1712571493.481390102, 161.317000000]: Completed trajectory execution with status TIMED_OUT ...

[ INFO] [1712571493.481824997, 161.317000000]: Execution completed: TIMED_OUT

[ INFO] [1712571493.502545506, 161.331000000]: ABORTED: TIMED_OUT

[ INFO] [1712571493.508375627, 161.339000000]: Controller 'robot_arm/arm_controller' successfully finished

It seems really strange to me that the Error message and Cancelling of the trajectory execution always ends less than a second before the controller successfully finishes.
I already tried modifying the joint limits (max velocity) but that didn't help. I also have a yaml file where I specify constraints for the arm_controller (goal_time, tracecotry: ... and goal: ... for all the joints). But also there nothing seemed to help.
Does someone have any idea how I can resolve this?
